# Recycle view multi level support

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have specific view in my application contain from  3 level Parent, Child, Child of child. there is any library to support render this ? and also support paging in each child ?

I use this [library](http://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/) now to handle 
 level view but it not support till now paging in child. So there is any other library that can help me ? i search but not found something till now.

Answer (score 0):

**you should try the TellH's library RecyclerTreeView**

[Link RecyclerTreeView](https://github.com/TellH/RecyclerTreeView)

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pQXE.gif)

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i don't think it support multiple level of views and paging. So, have you try it ? or what ?

Comment: @Azak check this library i think this will solve your problm https://github.com/TellH/RecyclerTreeView